# Delete first entry in CSV using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to repetitively safe datas in a csv file. I want to have for example always only 200 values in the file and delete the old files, so a fifo or queue. I am currently trying different solutions, but so far without success. Besides I hope to achieve this in only one csv file. Here is the function as I imagine it using pandas. I am happy about suggestions and comments.

```
def pop(self):
    df = pd.read_csv(self.file)
    df.drop(columns=1, inplace = True)
    df.to_csv(self.file, index = False)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the only way to do it with CSV files; read it all into memory, drop the first column, then write it out.

At best, you could do it row by row, so you're not limited by the size of the memory, and you'd be writing to a new file (then renaming), so you could potentially recover from an interruption or error.

Comment: You should write them into a file before you drop them. Otherwise you shouldn't find anything inside the csv.

Comment: are you trying to pop rows or columns?, did you try this code because it seems ok...

Answer (score 0):

in the end this worked for me : df.drop(1, inplace = True) ... thanks for your help !